# Execute Code First Migrations on Azure with Remote Connection String

Tags: azure, ef-code-first, azure-web-app-service, entity-framework-migrations

I am publishing an Azure Web App, and I'm running into a strange issue executing code first migrations.

The remote connection string for this database is working just fine if I do not check "Execute Code First Migrations".

[image: Publish Web]

However, if I check the box, a strange connection string with a curious misspelling, "ConnetionString", gets injected into the remote web.config:

```
<add name="DbContext_DatabasePublish" connectionString="DbContext_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This, of course, is not a valid connection string and the EF initializer throws this exception

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0

The publish behavior is also the same whether the local connection string refers to a localdb, or the connection string is not defined in the local web.config at all.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have filed a bug with the EF Team. If you are able to reproduce this issue again and provide me with the steps that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this behavior is still present in VS 2015, including the misspelling mentioned above. I only have a local database specified in my web.config. I'm using Application Settings on Azure to store the remote connection string (so I don't need any reference to it locally). It's not very obvious that if you do this, then you'll need to specify two connection strings.

Comment: I have this exact same error. I agree with Loren, I just spent about 3 hours trying to figure out that I need two connection strings, and it still doesn't execute code first migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure, I ultimately had to define connection strings for both `DbContext` and `DbContext_DatabasePublish` in order to get the migrations to execute. This [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2012/06/12/deployment-in-visual-studio-2012-rc-using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438730/94853) ultimately lead me to this conclusion.

I'm not sure why I'm not seeing more references to this issue though. It seems like it would be a common problem.